# How to change contact picture in Windows 8 People app for linked contacts?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-people-app

I link contacts together in people app. Very usefull feature for me. But how can I change picture of contact? For example I link together Skype, Facebook and Gmail accounts of somebody and People app show me picture for example from Facebook for this contact. But I want set picture from Skype or Gmail. Or remove picture completely for example.

Is it possible? I easily can do it on my Windows Phone 7.5, in same People app. Does Microsoft forget about this functional in windows 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there's currently no way to select which photo is displayed by the contact.

This was the [case in the previews](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/answers?tId=f6435a63-1643-46d4-b05d-27c0a63304b2), and is still the case in the first release:

> The profile picture cannot be changed as to which account Twitter or Windows Live uses. We understand what you would like to do but the developers have not provided a way to change this. It may change in the released version but we have not been notified of the changes.

You also can't change the contact picture from the web interface into people (going to Outlook.com and switching to "People").

Comment: It's a pity. I hope they fix it someday.

Comment: No change in the latest update. I thought this would be pretty key when they are trying to create a visually rich interface with the photos being used in email, sharing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the .eml files located in:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Indexed\LiveComm\43903dc7214d4360\120712-0049\People\AddressBook
```

Add the "From" column in the Windows Explorer view, it makes it a lot easier to see what's what. Open the .eml you want and right click on the Sender, Add to Outlook Contacts. Add the picture, save.

If you're just adding people with phone numbers (or other contact info that isn't an email address), they will automatically be added with an email address of a@a.com, if you have multiples, make sure to create a new contact entry when you save.